# Integration of kibana in custom application

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

i am very new to EKL Stack and for my project we have requirement to integrate kibana in our custom applications dashboard. 
So we are capturing the data through logstash and able to see it in kibana . But for our requirement we have to integrate kibana inside our local applications dashboard so on clicking on some link  we should open the page and show the graph in our application .
So is it possible to integrate the show kibana charts inside our custom application.
Or we have to query elastic search and create similar UI as kibana to show the trends .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can embbed the link in iframe and play around with dashboard using jquery.
You can use link like mentioned below with embed=true in URL.
http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/My-Dashboard?**embed=true**&_g=(filters:!()

This will hide all the extra things on your kibana dashboard and it will become a read only dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed dashboard, visualisation and search in web pages, with the share button: [image: Share button], which usually on the top right of the Kibana interface. It gives you an html iframe and a direct link.

More information on [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/dashboard.html#sharing-dashboards).